# Entity framework, database-first - disable lazy loading for specific navigation property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lazy-loading

Is there a way to disable lazy loading for given, specific navigation property?

I have database-first aproach, and I need to disable lazy loading for one given navigation property, because table that is connected to is so huge, that it makes my app load long time.

I tried to delete this prop from edmx model, but it broke all my LINQ to Entities queries that use this prop (even when it's loaded by .Include()).

**NotSupportedException**

> The specified type member 'TimesheetWorklog' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

I found one way to do that, but it's not perfect. 
I created Partial class and moved this property to that class, to make it no-virtual, and disable lazy-loading, but edmx is still generating this prop in base model and makes me to discard changes whenever I update my edmx.

Thanks!
Kris

Comment: You can easily disable the lazy loading for a single navigation property by simply not accessing it. Also this might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24022957/entity-framework-how-to-disable-lazy-loading-for-specific-query

Comment: Ok, you are right, but in my case I need to load it almost always, but never whole, huge, table, only a part of it. Now it is gathered by separate query, where only a part of table is fetched.