# EF Core enable Lazy Loading conditionally

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, lazy-loading

I am looking for a possible way to enable Lazy Loading in my `DbContext` but not all the time, only in specific instances when I need it. Because of issues like the N+1 queries with large datasets and JSON serialization traversing object properties and serializing my entire database I usually do not want Lazy Loading. However, in some instances I do want it. When generating reports I load a top-level object and many child objects in order to populate the report fields. Due to the nature of the schema this would need 30 or more `Include()` and `ThenInclude()` calls without Lazy Loading.

Is there a way to enable Lazy Loading conditionally when doing a query? I tried using 2 `DbContexts`, with one extending the other and enabling Lazy Loading, like this:

```
public class MyLazyContext : MyContext
{
    public MyLazyContext(DbContextOptions<MyLazyContext> options) : base(options) { }

    protected override OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseLazyLoadingProxies();
    }
}
```

And injecting them separately as dependencies. The constructor had a problem with passing `DbContextOptions<MyLazyContext>` to the base constructor requiring `DbContextOptions<MyContext>` so I changed them both to `DbContextOptions<MyContext>`. While this worked in my web application, my unit tests were broken due to how my generic class activators worked for `DbContext` - this got me thinking that this approach was code smell so I started looking for a better solution.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use [`ChangeTracker.LazyLoadingEnabled`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.changetracker.lazyloadingenabled?view=efcore-2.1) property:

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether navigation properties for tracked entities will be loaded on first access.
>
> The default value is true.

e.g.

```
context.ChangeTracker.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
var query = context.Set<…>()...;
```

Comment: Looks like what I need. However since I want it disabled normally and only enabled for certain cases, I set `ChangeTracker.LazyLoadingEnabled = false` in the constructor of my `DbContext` and then explicity set it `true` in controllers where it is needed.

Comment: Sure, sounds reasonable.

Comment: @Valuator which one is faster