# Include all related data of an entity

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework-core, lazy-loading

I am currently using Lazy Proxies with ef-Core. For the most of my queries I really like and need the lazy loading, but I have one particular query which has a lot of dependencies to other entities.

Which looks something like this:

```
- Model
    - ICollection<Model2>
        - ICollection<Model3>
            - Model4
                - Model5
                - Model6
```

For this query it would be better to just load everything at once, it is a performance improvement of about 200%.

My question now, is there any way to just straight up load all related data?

What I am currently doing is something like this:

```cs
var entity1 = await DbContext.Entites1.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == 1);

var entities2 = await DbContext.Entry(entity1).Collection(x => x.Entites2).Query().ToListAsync();
foreach (var entity2 in entities2)
{
    var entities3 = await DbContext.Entry(entity2).Collection(x => x.Entites3).Query().Include(x => x.Entity4).ThenInclude(x => x.Entity5).Include(x => x.Entity4).ThenInclude(x => x.Entity6).ToListAsync();

    item.LessonEntries = entities3;
}
```

This is already way better, but it still does multiple queries.

If this is not possible, could this be achieved with the `Include` and `ThenInclude` methods to load all related data with only one query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So actually, this question got asked several times already and somehow I didn't notice. Therefor I'll link the correct answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51848257/ef-core-enable-lazy-loading-conditionally/51848495#51848495).

You can enable and disable it by setting the `LazyLoadingEnabled` property on the `ChangeTracker` property of your `DBContext` instance.